# combine x-taglib with c-taglib on <x:set> and <c-foreach>

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

can is use a x-taglib var in a c-foreach

like:

```
<x:set var="logrows" select="$doc/properties/entry[@key='foo.bar']"></x:set>

<c:forEach items="${bar.foo}" var="log" begin="0" step="1" varStatus="i" end="${logrows}">

</c:foreach>
```

thx

Comment: yeah i tried it. but is seams that it needed a precasting or something.

without leaving the second <x:set> i get a "entry=null" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind I solved it myself with a kind of preCasting:

```
<x:set var="tmp" select="$doc/properties/entry[@key='foo.bar']" />
<x:set var="logrows" select='number($tmp)'/>    
<c:forEach items="${bar.foo}" var="log" begin="1" step="1" varStatus="i" end="${logrows}">
```